# Can not create an ongoing int

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm stuck on how I should approach creating an ongoing `int` for my website that I can adjust myself if needed and it will increment every (example) Saturday. I was thinking I would save it into the database somehow and then just edit from there if U needed to. Is there a better way?

This is what I have so far(it's not much, I'm stuck)

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    InvoiceWeekViewModel vm = new InvoiceWeekViewModel();
    vm.InvoiceId= .... ;
    return View();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Idea : If you get the current week number, it gets incremented every week,

Comment: Yep, i was typing a solution for something like an id each week. But the weeknumber itself is better....

Comment: I suspect X/Y problem, can you describe *why* you need this number?

Comment: @EBrown Well this number is gonna be used as a refrence to the invoice, eg. this week is Invoice No. 25. Every Friday ill be creating the invoice so Saturday is the new week hence new Invoice number. Ill be using that number to grab whatever information I need for that invoice. ( Is that enough information?).

Comment: @Shyju Yes that is also my idea, just dont know how to actually implement  it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the invoice configuration in database, I suggest following fields.

```
Id InvoiceReferenceNo Year  Day         CreatedDate
1  51                  2016  Monday      2016-12-26
2  52                  2016  Sunday      2017-01-01
3   1                  2017  Monday      2016-01-02
```

Now you have two approaches to get InvoiceReferenceNo,

1. Get the last row from database and check in your code need to create new referenceNo or used previous one.

   ```
   if(currentDayName == "Monday" || currentYear > databaseYear)
   {
      // Generate new reference no and save in database.
   }
   else 
   { 
      // use existing 
   }
   ```
2. Create a procedure and when you call it. It return the reference no after check and generating it in database.

   ```
   Declare @CurrentDay VARCHAR
   Declare @CurrentYear int
   Declare @DbYear int

   SET @CurrentDay = DATENAME(dw,GETDATE())
   SET @CurrentYear = DATEPART(yy, GETDATE())

   Select @DbYear=[Year] from InvoiceConfig

   If(@CurrentDay == 'Monday' OR @CurrentYear > @DbYear)
   Begin
     -- generate new reference no
   End
   Else
   Begin
    -- get existing reference no
   End
   ```